# Java jdbc implementar concurrencia optimista con sql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

estoy realizando un crud de categorías de un producto en mysql donde la tabla tiene los siguientes campos:

```
id (int)
nombre(varchar)
descripcion(varchar)
```

Mis métodos actualizar y eliminar del `CategoriaDAO` son los siguientes:

```
public boolean actualizarOptimista(Categoria oldCategoria, Categoria newCategoria) throws SQLException {
        resp = false;
        try {
            ps = CON.conectar().prepareStatement("UPDATE categoria SET nombre=?, descripcion=? WHERE id=? and nombre=?and descripcion=?");
            ps.setString(1, newCategoria.getNombre());
            ps.setString(2, newCategoria.getDescripcion());
            ps.setInt(3, oldCategoria.getId());
            ps.setString(4, oldCategoria.getNombre());
            ps.setString(5, oldCategoria.getDescripcion());

            if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                resp = true;
            }
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            ps = null;
            CON.desconectar();
        }
        return resp;
    }

    public boolean eliminarOptimista(Categoria categoria) throws SQLException {
        resp = false;
        try {
            ps = CON.conectar().prepareStatement("delete from categoria WHERE id=? and nombre=? and descripcion=?");
            ps.setInt(1, categoria.getId());
            ps.setString(2, categoria.getNombre());
            ps.setString(3, categoria.getDescripcion());

            if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                resp = true;
            }
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            ps = null;
            CON.desconectar();
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

¿Me sirve la consulta del preparedStatement para controlar la concurrencia?
Para el crud sólo debo usar jdbc, nada de frameworks.

Desde ya muchas gracias